# Objective-C cast from (_bridge const void*) type to (NSString*)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, casting, bridge

I'm working on an iPhone application and I have extract a value from a method that is of type `_bridge const void *`.
But I need that this value to be converted to type `NSString`.

I saw that a classic cast has no effect.

```
 valueNSString = (NSString *) valueConstVoid
```

Comment: What type is it actually returning?

Comment: need more info about the original type.  you'll be using one of the bridged cast variants, but void * tells too little about what the bytes mean.  NSData might be right, but so might NSString or anything else.

Comment: The original type is a sequence of numbers that I have extract from a set of information that was returned by a property.
For some reason, however, this set of numbers is _bridge const void * type. I have never come across this kind of data and do not even know what it means _bridge.
The problem is that I need to provide this data to a method that accepts only as NSString type, so I need to convert it to NSString.

Comment: So the property is `const void *`?

Comment: And you thought any type can be converted to any other type just by casting it?

Comment: Sounds like bogus code;  casting objc objects to void* and back to an object type is a sure sign the code is bogus (unless you are going through some C/C++ API).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it could be bridged to NSData first and only then turned into NSString with the appropriate constructor.

So what we have here is a pointer to void. Pointer to void is just a location in memory where your physical object (or byte sequence) representation starts. We don't know what it is and that is the issue. Casting is merely assignment of a particular type pointer. In other words typed pointer allows you to know where specific properties are and where actual physical representation ends. Let's try this. Stop debugger at line after `value` assigned and type `po value` in the debugger. Tell us what you see as a printout.

Comment: How? Can you give me an example with code? Thank you!

Comment: @user2136333 I need more info to see how you get this value. Once supplied, I'll give the example right away.

Comment: The original type is a sequence of numbers that I have extract from a set of information that was returned by a property. For some reason, however, this set of numbers is _bridge const void * type. I have never come across this kind of data and do not even know what it means _bridge. The problem is that I need to provide this data to a method that accepts only as NSString type, so I need to convert it to NSString.

Comment: @user2136333 not enough info.  Which property? What set of information?

Comment: The information I have extract is a ID number that is the identifier of the facebook user. And I need that this ID be converted to a NSString. Do you know another way to obtain with the  API the ID of a facebook user?

Answer (score 0):

`(__bridge const void*)` is not a type but a cast. So you value probably is of type `const void *`. If you are sure that it's a pointer to an `NSString` you can cast it as follows:

```
const void *value;
NSString *stringValue = (__bridge NSString *)value;
```

Comment: The question is then, why would it be declared as `void *`?  Seems very dodgy to me...

Comment: what is the point of __bridge in this context?

Comment: Ok, i try your snippet and

Comment: I have a error of this type...

Comment: incompatible types casting NSNumber to NSString with a _bridge cast. So my type is a NSnumber and not a const void? I don't understand...

Comment: @user2136333 you cannot do what you want to do using a cast.  You need to provide a method to format the sequence of numbers into whatever Objective-C object you want, which will require iterating over the sequence (most likely).  If you wrote this class then why is it defined as `const void *` in the first place.

Comment: @user2136333 You should provide more information (code). Otherwise your question cannot be answered.